# Staying on the same page in Spring

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm using Spring and would like to find out if there is some technique that can be used to stay on the same page.  So, to be more clear, after you click on a link and the handler executes, there is some condition which dictates that the browser should remain on (or be redirected/forwarded to) the page the browser was currently on.  Beehive, which is built on top of Struts, has a way to do this and I'm wondering if Spring has something similar.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the use case. Are you submitting a form or something similar that could be submitted through XHR instead? If you can't use XHR, a simple solution is to have the controller return a view to the current page, possibly with some additional state information.

Comment: In some cases a form is being submitted but not all.  I'm not using XHR.  In the handler method how can I get the view to the current page?  That's what I'm wondering about.